# Svelte namespace components export

Tags: svelte-3, svelte-component

In docs there is a [Tags section](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-tags) with such stuff:

> A lowercase tag, like `<div>`, denotes a regular HTML element. A capitalised tag, such as `<Widget>` or `<Namespace.Widget>`, indicates a component.

How export such `<Namespace.Widget>` or `<Namespace.Whatever>`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I think what this is referring to is when you export multiple `.svelte` files from a single `.js` file and import them all under a single namespace in another component... It's not very well documented but it works.

If you have the following project structure:

```
─ src/
  ├── child/
  │   ├── index.js
  │   ├── One.svelte
  │   └── Two.svelte
  └── Parent.svelte
```

In `child/index.js` export the 2 components inside the same folder:

```js
export { default as One } from './One.svelte'
export { default as Two } from './Two.svelte'
```

Then in `Parent.svelte` import all of the components under a single namespace instead of importing each individual component:

```html
<script>
  import * as Something from './child'
</script>

<Something.One />
<Something.Two />
```

You can test the functionality in the REPL like this one https://svelte.dev/repl/18f41adb56fa46ff8b25cad7c1a388a4?version=3.38.3 it's just  not as useful without a proper file structure.

Comment: How do I accomplish this with the namespace still being a component? For example: if I have a namespace of `List` I would like to use `import List from 'List'` and use it like so `<List><List.Item /><List.Item /></List>` I have tried several approaches but I can't get this working with out Typescript screaming at me.

Comment: @CraigHowell Not sure about TS but the method described above really only works with all the components being assigned to the namespace variable. You could `export {default as _} from './Component.svelte'` and use it like `<Something._ />` after the wildcard import. But Svelte isn't really built for exporting multiple sub-components from a single component. Personally I would just keep related components in the same folder and name them `List`, `ListItem`, `ListHeader` etc. You should be able to export multiple components from a single .ts file for a cleaner import if that's your concern.