# How to avoid name conflict between components and API types?

Tags: rest, model-view-controller, components

For example, a `GET` request to `/articles/1` can have its result typed with the name `Article`. But when displaying this article, the component could also be named `Article`.

How do you resolve name conflicts between components and API types?

Comment: Name collisions are usually resolved with namespaces. Not sure what language you use.

Comment: In this case, I'm using Svelte

Comment: Never heard of that. This appears to be a similar question, maybe it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68237043/svelte-namespace-components-export

Comment: This is not a Svelte question, though. It's more of a MVC question. If you have the view `Article` and the model `Article`, how do you name them both?

Comment: I depends on what the model and the view contains. If the model contains the properties of the article e.g. creation data, modification date, history, author, title, content, etc. then the Article is good for it. As of the view it is just a template you use to display the Article, so it can be ArticleView, ArticleTemplate, ArticleContainer, ArticleRepresentation, ArticlePresentation, etc. You can even have multiple different templates and the user can choose, so for example SimpleArticleTemplate, DetailedArticleTemplate, MinimalisticArticeTemplate, etc.